# if 3 random variables are independent, then any pair is independent given the remaining random variable

Tags: random-variables, independence

How do I prove the following:
$X,Y,Z$ are independent, then any pair is independent given the remaining
random variable.

I know that $E(X|Z)=E(X) $ and $E(Y|Z)=E(Y)$

so $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)=E(X|Z)E(Y|Z)$

does it imply that $E(X|Z)E(Y|Z)=E(XY|Z)$

On the other hand, if $X,Y,Z$ are pairwise independent, how do I disprove that any pair is independent given the remaining random variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X,Y,Z$ are independent, hence, $P(X,Y,Z) = P(X) P(Y) P(Z)$. Then,

$$P(X,Y \mid Z) = \frac{P(X,Y,Z)}{P(Z)} = \frac{P(X) P(Y) P(Z)}{P(Z)}$$
This proves that $X,Y \mid Z$ are independent, since $P(X,Y \mid Z) = P(X)P(Y)$. The same proof goes to the other cases.

For the case you want to disprove, just use the following [counter-example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence):

[image]

You can easily check that they are pairwise independent. But their collection is not independent. Just doing some calculations:

$$
P(X,Y \mid Z) = \frac{P(Z \mid Y,X)P(X,Y)}{P(Z)}= \frac{P(Z \mid Y,X)P(X)P(Y)}{P(Z)}
$$

But $P(Z=1 \mid X=1, Y=1)=0 \neq P(Z=1)=0.5$. So we conclude that $P(X,Y \mid Z) \neq P(X)P(Y)$ which is what we wanted to disprove.

Comment: Does this proof miss an additional step? The problem is asking to prove pairwise independence, i.e. $P(X, Y) = P(X) P(Y)$ but not $P(X, Y|Z) = P(X)P(Y)$?

Comment: The question is "any pair is independent given the remaining random variable".